# Get instance of dynamic type using Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, dynamictype

```
      var dataStore = default(dynamic);
      _kernel.Bind<dynamic>().ToConstant(dataStore).InTransientScope();
```

how do I get it this instance (or a specific instance of `dynamic` type) using Ninject?

I think I can then do `_kernel.Get<dynamic>()`. But just thinking that binding an instance(specific thing) to `dynamic`(so much generic) type is not good.

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to register/inject `dynamic`. Usually, you'll want an IoC to resolve a dependency, `dynamic` isn't a dependency.

Comment: Yes I agree. But in this particular case I'm doing it just for ease of not passing it down through all constructors. #laziness ;)